# New Organization Button Missing

Tags: contacts, organization

On CiviCRM 4.7.22 Drupal 7, I'm missing the "New Organization" button under Current Employer. I can't seem to find figure out whether this is a settings problem or not. A previous version of CiviCRM had it.

And I haven't made any changes to the contact types or relationships.[image]

I also checked the reserved profiles. No changes on "new_organization".

Comment: I'm on 4.7.21 and it isn't there.  But if you go to dmaster.demo.civicrm.org it's there on 4.7.25.  Must have been a bug that's been fixed I guess.

Comment: Strange thing is that on a clean 4.7.22 install, the "New Organization" button shows.

Comment: Also, just updated to 4.7.23 and no changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ran into this upgrading to 4.7.22

For some reason (which I have not investigated) the reserved profiles for *New Individual*, *New Organization*, etc got their profile ID appended to their "name".

If you query the UFGroup entity in the API explorer like this:

```
$result = civicrm_api3('UFGroup', 'get', array(
  'sequential' => 1,
  'title' => "New Organization",
));
```

You should have a result like:

```
{
    "id": "5",
    "is_active": "1",
    "group_type": "Organization,Contact",
    "title": "New Organization",
    "add_captcha": "0",
    "is_map": "0",
    "is_edit_link": "0",
    "is_uf_link": "0",
    "is_update_dupe": "0",
    "is_cms_user": "0",
    "is_reserved": "1",
    "name": "new_organization_5", // note the appended ID, 'new_organization' should be the value here
    "is_proximity_search": "0",
    "is_error": 0
}
```

Digging [here](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/8b1e918c8246907e2b7dd38d94662a24116e65e4/js/Common.js#L831), [here](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/8b1e918c8246907e2b7dd38d94662a24116e65e4/CRM/Core/Resources.php#L686) and [here](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/ac525af0bc91528c3d3c2706fabaffef15b736e6/CRM/Core/BAO/UFGroup.php#L3303) found that when the method to get the profile links is called with no params, the profiles names are hardcoded to the default `'new_individual', 'new_organization', 'new_household'`

To fix it you'll need to revert back the profile "name" either via the API explorer:

```
$result = civicrm_api3('UFGroup', 'create', array(
    'sequential' => 1,
    'id' => 5,
    "is_active": "1",
    "group_type": "Organization,Contact",
    "title": "New Organization",
    "add_captcha": "0",
    "is_map": "0",
    "is_edit_link": "0",
    "is_uf_link": "0",
    "is_update_dupe": "0",
    "is_cms_user": "0",
    "is_reserved": "1",
    "name": "new_organization",
    "is_proximity_search": "0",
));
```

Or if you have access to and you feel more comfortable, querying the database directly:

```
update civicrm_uf_group set name="new_organization" where id=5;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, thank you! This was perfect. I used phpyadmin to query the statement you gave me, then clear cache in CiviCRM.